# Saving scrollview position using CATiledView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am using a scroll view to display a CATiledView of some large images. When the user leaves the app, then comes back, I would like the app to automatically scroll and zoom to the place where the user was when the left the app.

I am getting the zoomLevel saved, but I cant figure out how to save the scroll position then have it scroll to that position.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `contentOffset` and `setContentOffset::`